# Parsing JSON data from a URL

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create  function that can parse JSON from a url. Here's what I have so far:

```
function get_json(url) {
    http.get(url, function(res) {
        var body = '';
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
            var response = JSON.parse(body);
                return response;
        });
    });
}

var mydata = get_json(...)
```

When I call this function I get errors. How can I return parsed JSON from this function?

Comment: "I get errors" - What errors ?

Comment: What, no URL?  How are we supposed to help you with this problem?

Comment: Your `return response;` won't be of any use. You can pass a function as an argument to `get_json`, and have it receive the result. Then in place of `return response;`, invoke the function. So if the parameter is named `callback`, you'd do `callback(response);`.

Comment: Here's an example url: http://webapp.armadealo.com/home.json

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `return response;` won't be of any use. You can pass a function as an argument to `get_json`, and have it receive the result. Then in place of `return response;`, invoke the function. So if the parameter is named `callback`, you'd do `callback(response);`.

```
// ----receive function----v
function get_json(url, callback) {
    http.get(url, function(res) {
        var body = '';
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
            var response = JSON.parse(body);
// call function ----v
            callback(response);
        });
    });
}

         // -----------the url---v         ------------the callback---v
var mydata = get_json("http://webapp.armadealo.com/home.json", function (resp) {
    console.log(resp);
});
```

Passing functions around as callbacks is essential to understand when using NodeJS.

Answer (score 13):

In case someone is looking for an solution that does not involve callbaks

```
    function getJSON(url) {
        var resp ;
        var xmlHttp ;

        resp  = '' ;
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        if(xmlHttp != null)
        {
            xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, false );
            xmlHttp.send( null );
            resp = xmlHttp.responseText;
        }

        return resp ;
    }
```

Then you can use it like this

```
var gjson ;
gjson = getJSON('./first.geojson') ;
```

Answer (score 5):

The HTTP call is asynchronous, so you must use a callback in order to fetch a resultant value. A `return` call in an asynchronous function will just stop execution.

```
function get_json(url, fn) {
  http.get(url, function(res) {
    var body = '';
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
      body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
      var response = JSON.parse(body);
      fn(response);
    });
  });
};

get_json(url, function(json) {
  // the JSON data is here
});
```

In this example, `function(json) {}` is passed into the `get_json()` function as `fn()`, and when the data is ready, `fn()` is called, allowing you to fetch the JSON.