# Google maps, get coordinate for direction given a URL

Tags: android, web-services, google-maps

I have an android application and I want to allow users to import directions via a URL provided by google maps. Once the URL is passed I would like to use Google Map Web Services to get the geojson string of the directions which I can save and plot onto map later.  Here is an example [map](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/39.276479,-76.6241204/39.2817433,-76.6211442/@39.2791926,-76.6219567,1213m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m14!4m13!1m10!3m4!1m2!1d-76.6225531!2d39.2759153!3s0x89c80343a6b10877:0xffb49a9d98afb74e!3m4!1m2!1d-76.6176209!2d39.2834359!3s0x89c80360ad0050dd:0xfe3c13c8f21c7a8e!1m0!3e1) with directions that I created. I'm assuming there is a way to parse the URL in order to get the [waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Waypoints) that I'll pass to the service but I'm unable to figure out the structure of the url. Does anybody know how I can get the geojson string given the map url above?

Thanks

Comment: Did you look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440589/parsing-json-data-from-a-url

Comment: My problem isn't parsing JSON, that is the result I want to get from the web service call. The problem is parsing the URL to get the way points to pass to the web service