# AWS Lambda Parse JSON (Unexpected token)

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to get a Lambda function to access an API and return the JSON.

## API

> http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a

P.S This API ID is the demo one provided by OW.

## Lambda Code

```
 var jsonurl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a";
 var data = JSON.parse(jsonurl);
 exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  console.log(data);
  context.done(null, data);  // SUCCESS with message
};
```

## Error

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unexpected token h",
  "errorType": "SyntaxError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Object.parse (native)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:3:17)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:456:26)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:356:32)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)",
    "Module.require (module.js:364:17)",
    "require (module.js:380:17)"
  ]
}
```

## Log output

```
START RequestId: 8ca0fbd1-eee5-11e5-b9dd-31048a8d5a45 Version: $LATEST
Syntax error in module 'index': SyntaxError
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
END RequestId: 8ca0fbd1-eee5-11e5-b9dd-31048a8d5a45
REPORT RequestId: 8ca0fbd1-eee5-11e5-b9dd-31048a8d5a45  Duration: 173.76 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 9 MB
```

Can anyone see the problem?

What I would like is for lambda to get the json and return it, so anyone looking at my API url will see the results from the Open Weather API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a URL to `JSON.parse()`, not a JSON string. First you need to go get the JSON data from the URL using something like `http.get()`. Perhaps check out the answers to this similar question: [Parsing JSON data from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440589/parsing-json-data-from-a-url)

Comment: When I use http.get() in Lambda I get the error message :  "errorMessage": "http is not defined",

Comment: Well did you define it? `var http = require('http');`